# Why do amides react differently with PCl5?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, halides

In a reaction involving $\ce{PCl5}$ and any reactant containing oxygen atom, it generally takes out the oxygen and put chlorine their due to formation of strong bond between phosphorus and oxygen.

But, in case of amides like $\ce{RCONH2}$, when they react with $\ce{PCl5}$, a cyanide is formed. Why?

Comment: PCl5 does react on oxygen which forms R(Cl4PO)C=NH. Elimination of Cl4POH forms the nitrile, RCN. Cl4POH decompoes to  POCl3 and HCl.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/65852/dehydration-of-amide-with-pcl5